# Excel VBA Find function not returning an integer value, can't see what I am doing wrong

Tags: excel, vba

so I am writing an excel marco to automate some manual tasks. I've hit a wall in a function I am writing, it fails to return a integer value to me for use in the sub I am calling it from. I feel like this is simple but I can't for the life of me see what I am doing wrongly.

```
Function Find_Header(SearchTerm As String) As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
With Sheets("DATA").Range("A:CZ")
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=SearchTerm, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    lookat:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Rng, True
        Find_Header = Rng.Column
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If
End With
End Function
```

From witin a sub I call it thusly:

```
Find_Header SearchTerm:="Status"
```

And since the term 'Status' is within the range specific and is Column number 5 I expect to see 'Find_Header' is equal to 5 within my sub, however as soon as the function ends the variable is lost, what I am not doing to retain this value in the sub routine?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I 'borrowed' most of this code from google searching, I will clean it up to meet my exact needs when I get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the result in a variable - for example:

```
Dim iFoundCol as Integer
iFoundCol = Find_Header(SearchTerm:="Status")
```

Comment: Of course I do, for some reason I was assuming the Function name would be my variable, thanks for pointing out the obvious, I am no longer stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

A function returns a value which needs to be stored in a variable, you can't simply just call the function